# Difference between "while (...) continue;" and "while (...);"?

Tags: c

In **The Linux Programming Interface**, in some parts (for example section 26.3.1) the following code is written

```
while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
    continue;
```

What is the difference between the above code and the following?

```
while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
```

I think the second is better, but the mentioned book is a reference book so I have this question.

I looked in two books (The Linux Programming inTerface, Advanced programming in UNIX environment) and also I searched google.

Comment: FWIW, _"Advanced programming in UNIX environment"_ is kiiiinda obsolete thesedays: Linux isn't Unix, after-all.

Comment: I can think of one significant purpose for that `continue` position: a breakpoint in a debug-build. You ever try to shove a debug breakpoint in a colon-terminated loop expression without having to resort to show-disassembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `continue` in your first example exists to make it a more readable loop and serves no functional purpose. The `;` alone can be easily missed. Likewise for `{}`

Comment: any experience programmer who overlooks a `;` or a `{}` is suspect in my book. Experience teaches us these are important, and should be easy to spot.